# Changing "FillInChoice" of Column in Powershell via PnP or CSOM

Tags: pnp-powershell

Below is a part of a very long powershell script I have:

```
Add-PnpField  -List $ListName -DisplayName “Title • Function” -InternalName “TitleFunction” -Type Choice -Choices “Account Executive”,”Vice President”,”Digital Planner”

$field = Get-PnpField -List $ListName -Identity “Title • Function”
$field.**(Something)**.FillInChoice = $true
$field.update()
```

The second part does not work. I've tried a bunch of stuff. I'd just like to tick on "FillInChoice" which appears in the items SchemaXML but does not appear to be quickly editable.

Thoughts? I work well with the Pnp stuff but not so much beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PnP Powershell currently doesn't support `FillInChoice` property. So, you need to use CSOM code with powershell.

Basically, we are type casting the Field to Field Choice and then updating the property.

Try and modify the below powershell as per your list name and column:

```
$path = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\"
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "$($path)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

$siteUrl = "https://sitecollectionurl"
$username = "user.name@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "password"

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.RequestTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
$ctx.AuthenticationMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode]::Default
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$List = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName")
$ctx.Load($List)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve field
$field = $List.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("TitleFunction");

#type casting field as Choice field
$fieldChoice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldChoice]).Invoke($ctx,$field)

$ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#setting the FillInChoice property
$fieldChoice.FillInChoice = $true
$fieldChoice.Update()
$ctx.Load($fieldChoice)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Ensure that the above dll files are present. If you have a different path, please modify accordingly.

If these dll files are not present, please install the SharePoint Online CSOM SDK and change the path as per your file system.

Download link - [SPO CSOM SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Am I able to skip the vast majority of the code and instead do something like: $field = Get-PnpField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName ???[br]I did that and it did not work, seemingly because of the .ctx requested in the Invoke.

Comment: @JoeFedorowicz - it wont work, please see my edited answer. You need to only modify the site collection url, list name and the internal column name in the above code. It will work as is :)

Comment: Hi I eventually got there with a few tweaks on your code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A little dated but this can now be done in PnP:
Set-PnPField -Identity $field -Values @{FillInChoice=$true} -UpdateExistingLists

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Weird I know but it worked for me.

```
$choice.FillInChoice = "False"
$choice.Update();
```